# javascript drop down list equal to the same number of textbox

Tags: javascript

I have one drop-down list that has numbers 1-10 and a proceed button.
What I want is, when the user select a specific number and the user click the proceed button, it should display a number of textboxes equal to the number of selected in the drop-down list.

is it possible to doit with a loop? or any suggestions?

Comment: What have you already tried? - SO is a service to assist with coding problems, not doing it all for you. This would be a simple issue of determining the number selected and setting up a loop that appends the specified number of textboxes into an empty div.

Comment: Yes it is posible to do it but no need to use loop. Just add an `addEventListener` to button. please provide provide some code.

Comment: actually sir, im still confused what to do.. i cant make a move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option - using jQuery cos its much cooler than just plain JS - first determine the number of textboxes required based on the value of the select list. Then create a string with the required number of textboxes and third - apply that HTMl to the empty div. Note that the reason for building the textboxes as a string and then adding it to the div is that this requires only one alteration to the DOM - doing it on each iteration would require altering the DOM numerous times. Its fine if you don't want to use jQuery - as the other answers demonstrate - all things done in jQ can be done in JS - but its just more fun to use.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selection').change(function(){
    var num = $(this).val();
    var HTML='';
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
      HTML += "<input type='text' name='textBox"+i+"' /><br/>"
      }
    $('#newDiv').html(HTML);
  })                  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for = "selection"> Enter the number of textboxes required</label>
<select id="selection">
  <option disabled selected></option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
  </select>

<hr/>
<div id="newDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `addEventListener`, you can generate the textboxes as:

```
function create(param) {
    //'use strict';
    var i, target = document.getElementById('screens');
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for (i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
        target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="Fname"><br /><br />';
    }
}

document.getElementById('createTextboxes').addEventListener('change', function () {
    create(this.value);
}, false);
```

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rJPH/84/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Pure Js and Fast

```js
function creator(){
var tb = document.getElementById("generator").value
var area = document.getElementById("tbArea");

var childcount = area.childNodes.length;
   if(childcount != 0)
     {  for(var i = childcount-1; i > -1;i--)    
           { 
       area.removeChild(area.childNodes[i]);
           }  
     }
for(var i =0; i < tb; i++){
   var tbox = document.createElement('input');
     document.getElementById("tbArea").appendChild(tbox);
      }

}

document.getElementById("generator").onchange = creator;
```

```html
<select id='generator'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
  <option value='7'>7</option>
  <option value='8'>8</option>
  <option value='9'>9</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
</select>

<div id='tbArea'></div>
```

Comment: Ok create a button and read all the values of input field through JS or whatever you like... Then display